# thread start address

Tags: windows, dll, multithreading

How can i identify exact location in a method with the following information:

"abcd.dll!CMyclass::CMymethod+0x45"

Actually this is the start address of a thread, i got this string as a start address for a thread with the help of a process monitoring tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Attach your debugger, go to the entrypoint of CMyclass::CMymethod, switch to the disassembly view, go down 69 bytes (=0x45).